# Assigning a name to an output file with a string variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a program to concatenate 3 csv files into a single new output csv file. As part of this I have to ask the user for the name they want to use for the output filename. My problem is that my output filename is declared in the arguments of the function and therefore, I get an error on the first line of this function because myFile is not declared (see 2 lines later for the declaration).

```
def concatenate(indir="C:\\Conc", outfile="C:\\Conc\\%s.csv" %myFile):
    os.chdir(indir)
    myFile = input("Please type the name of the file: ")
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["Symbol", "Name", "LastSale", "MarketCap", "ADR TSO", "IPOYear", "Sector", "Industry", "Summary Quote", " "]
    for filename in fileList:
        print("merging " + filename + "...")
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf = concatDf.sort_values(by=["Symbol"], axis=0, ascending=True)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
    print("Completed. Your merged file can be found at: " + outfile + "\n")
```

This function is called from a menu function (as below) so I was wondering if it's possible to pass it from the menu??

```
if choice == "1":
    myFile = input("Please type the name of the file: ")
    concatenate(myFile)
    menu()
```

But neither options seem to work because I always get an error saying that myFile is not declared. I know this is basic stuff but I'm scratching my head trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your reputation suggests you're new to stack overflow and your name suggests you're new to python. So welcome to both! Here's a quite verbose answer to hopefully make things clear.

There are a few issues here:

1. `concatenate()` takes two arguments, `indir` and `outdir`, but you're only passing one argument when you're calling it: `concatenate(myFile)`. Your arguments are what is called keyword arguments, since you've given them names (i.e. `indir` and `outdir`). When you're only passing one argument (`myFile`), without using the keyword, the `myFile` variable is passed as the first argument, which, in this case, is the `indir` (this doesn't happen yet in your code, as the error you're getting precedes it and stops it from being executed). However, you seem to want the `myFile` variable assigned to your `outfile` argument. You can achieve this by being explicit in your call to `concatenate()` like so: `concatenate(outfile=myFile)`. Now, your `indir` argument remains the default you've set (i.e. `"C:\\Conc"`), but your `outfile` argument has the value of `myFile`. This would, however, not fix your problem (detailed in point 2). I suggest you change the `outfile` argument to represent an output directory (see full example below).
2. This is where you get an error. Your `concatenate()` function has no knowledge of the `myFile` variable you've declared in your if-statement, as the function and your if-statement are different scopes. That's why function arguments exist, to pass data from one scope (your if-statement) to another scope (your function). So you get an error in your function saying that `myFile` is not declared because, to the function's eyes, it doesn't exist. It can only see `indir` and `outfile`, not `myFile`. Also, don't do string manipulation in arguments. I'm not sure how it works, but it surely doesn't work how you expect in this case.
3. You're asking the user for `myFile` twice. Once in the if-statement and once in your `concatenate()` function. You only need to ask for it once, I suggest to keep it in the function only.
4. Small correction: You should combine directory paths and filenames in a platform-independent manner. The `os` module has a function for that (`os.path.join()`, see example below). Paths in Windows and paths in Linux look different, the `os` module handles those differences for us:)

Here's a final suggestion, with comments, addressing all points:

```
# Import your modules
import pandas
import os  # <-- We're gonna need this

# Your code
# ...

# The concatenate function, with arguments having a default value, allowing to optionally specify the input directory and the output *directory* (not output file)
def concatenate(indir="C:\\Conc", outdir="C:\\Conc"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    myFile = input("Please type the name of the file: ")  # <-- We ask for the output filename here
    # Your code
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["Symbol", "Name", "LastSale", "MarketCap", "ADR TSO", "IPOYear", "Sector", "Industry", "Summary Quote", " "]
    for filename in fileList:
        print("merging " + filename + "...")
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf = concatDf.sort_values(by=["Symbol"], axis=0, ascending=True)

    # Saving the data
    # First, we need to create the full output path, i.e. the output directory + output filename. We use os.join.path() for that
    output_path = os.path.join(outdir, myFile)

    # The rest of your code
    concatDf.to_csv(output_path, index=None)  # <-- Note output_path, not outfile
    print("Completed. Your merged file can be found at: " + output_path + "\n")


# The if-statement calling the ´concatenate()´ function
if choice == "1":
    # We're calling concatenate() with no arguments, since we're asking for the filename within the function.
    # You could, however, ask the user for the input directory or output directory and pass that along, like this:
    # input_directory_from_user = input("Please type the path to the input directory: ")
    # output_directory_from_user = input("Please type the path to the output directory: ")
    # concatenate(indir=input_directory_from_user, outdir=output_directory_from_user)
    concatenate()
    menu()
```

Comment: thank you so much, this was so helpful. I voted it up, but I guess it's not public until I get a better reputation. You're right, I'm new to Stack Overflow and new to Python, and even new to programming. This helped a lot, ty

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Here on stack overflow, you can upvote answers and questions when you've gained enough reputation. As the asker of a question, you can also accept answers to indicate that the question has been solved (it's the checkmark next to the answer), and it doesn't require a minimum reputation. It will help us filter out which questions have been answered and which have not.